# Display missing values with Crosstable()

Tags: r, missing-data, crosstab

I'm trying to display a frequency table using `CrossTable()`.

I want it to display the same results as:

```
   table(mydata$union, exclude=NULL)
```

I can't find any documentation on this, but all I have is:

```
  CrossTable(mydata$union,digits=4)
```

Comment: You can just run `?CrossTable` to get the documentation.

Comment: Did my answer help or did you find some other way?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `gmodels::CrossTable` function does not deal with R type `NA`s. It seems to be heavily inspired by SPSS and SAS, which have different conventions for `NA`s. The `missing.include` argument that keeps or removes any unused factor levels doesn't seem very helpful either.

If you come from a SPSS background, I suggest doing something similar to what you do in SPSS: replacing `NA`s with a conventional value of 9999. You can run the `tidyr::replace_na` on your whole dataframe or on specific columns. Here is a small reproducible example:

```r
library(gmodels)
library(tidyr)

data <- mtcars
data$am[c(3, 7, 10)] <- NA                    # replace some values with NAs in am column for example purposes
data$am <- tidyr::replace_na(data$am, 9999)   # replace NAs with 9999 like would be the case in SPSS

gmodels::CrossTable(data$am, digits = 4, format = "SPSS")
#> 
#>    Cell Contents
#> |-------------------------|
#> |                   Count |
#> |             Row Percent |
#> |-------------------------|
#> 
#> Total Observations in Table:  32 
#> 
#>           |        0  |        1  |     9999  | 
#>           |-----------|-----------|-----------|
#>           |       17  |       12  |        3  | 
#>           |  53.1250% |  37.5000% |   9.3750% | 
#>           |-----------|-----------|-----------|
#> 
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>